# Use of a variable in psql script

Tags: xml, postgresql, psql

I want to write a multiple tables of a PostgreSQL database into an XML file.

The following script command does the job (I need mixed upper and lowercase for schema and table names):

```
SELECT table_to_xml('"DbSchema"."DbTable"', false, true, '');
```

However, I have to replace the name of the schema in every single line of code whenever I want to export another schema (this is not a big deal, but it is not elegant).

It would be elegant to set the schema for the whole script to "DbSchema". But I have not been able to find the correct syntax. The following example does not work (error message: relation "DbSchema" does not exist):

```
\set schema "DbSchema"

SELECT table_to_xml('"DbTable"', false, true, '');
```

Alternatively I could set a variable for the schema name. But the following code gives also an error message: missing FROM-clause entry for tabl "DbSchema":

```
\set dbschema "DbSchema"

SELECT table_to_xml(:dbschema."DbTable", false, true, '');
```

I tried many variants with and without quotation marks, but I don't find the correct syntax. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution is:

```
\set dbschema 'DbSchema'

SELECT table_to_xml('"' || :'dbschema' || '"."DbTable"', false, true, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
SELECT table_to_xml('"' || t.dbschema || '"."DbTable"', false, true, '')
FROM (VALUES ('DbSchema')) AS t (dbschema);
```

With psql you can do this like this

```
\set schema "DbSchema"

SELECT table_to_xml(:'schema' || '."DbTable"', false, true, '');
```

Comment: psql obviously does not concatenate the strings. I am using this SELECT statement in a psql script.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's it! I had to make one more change: '"."DbTable"' -- one more quotation mark in front of the dot.